# How do I change what the X button does on the Windows console window?

Tags: python, windows

I have a regular console window (Windows 8.1) in Python and I want to change what the close/X button does. When the game ends, it needs to do some clean up and stuff like that, so how do I override what it does?

Comment: What do you mean "a regular console window"?

Comment: I apologize, I should have specified. I'm running Windows 8.1.

Comment: I don't think you have any control over it.

Comment: You can't control that.  That console is running your Python program, not the other way around.

Comment: Okay, I thought I could change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can intercept the console close event by using [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to specify a function that is called for Ctrl-C, Ctrl-Break, console exit and system shutdown events. For the console exit event you cannot prevent the console from being destroyed but you *can* intercept the event and run some code. For example:

```
import sys
import time
import win32api

forever = True
handled_ctrl_type = None

def handler(ctrl_type):
    global forever, handled_ctrl_type
    forever = False
    handled_ctrl_type = ctrl_type
    print("HANDLER")
    return True

def main(args = None):
    win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(handler, True)
    n = 0
    while forever:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(n)
        n = n + 1
    print("exiting...", handled_ctrl_type)
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

If this is run (using Python 3) in a console and you hit Ctrl-C you should get something like this:

```
c:\src>python python\setconsolectrl.py
0
HANDLER
1
exiting... 0
```

where the 0 was the value for [CTRL_C_EVENT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242(v=vs.85).aspx). For console exit we should get 2 set here, so we can tell what kind of event was generated.

If you run this and hit the big red X to close the console, you can just see HANDLER being printed as the console gets destroyed. You should add some logging to a file to ensure all your cleanup is really getting called but this looks like it should solve your question.

Comment: The handler shouldn't be returning True. This prevents chaining to previously installed handlers. Thus a `CTRL_C_EVENT` never gets to the C runtime handler that raises a `SIGINT`, so Python's `SIGINT` handler never runs to raise a `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: It would be nice if a `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` could be handled by calling `FreeConsole` to continue running as a detached process. But with the current design it's already too late for that to work.